# python 3.8 breaks python 3.5 code using multiprocessing and globals

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I know globals are bad but I'm curious if there is more info about this surprising difference between python 3.5 and python 3.8 on macOS 10.15.6.

Why is the assignment of the global `client` in the `__main__` block ignored in the `foo()` function / process? Is there a way to write it so that it works consistently across python versions?

UPDATE: these first two pythons are in my /usr/local/bin, so they must have come from brew.

```
% python3.5 ./x.py
!!!Assigned client=repr({'hello': 1})
Using client=repr({'hello': 1})

% python3.8 ./x.py
!!!Assigned client=repr({'hello': 1})
Using client=repr(None)
```

If I use the non-brew /usr/bin/python3 it's 3.7.3 and works as I expect.

```
% /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.7.3

% /usr/bin/python3 ./x.py
/usr/bin/python3 ./x.py
!!!Assigned client=repr({'hello': 1})
Using client=repr({'hello': 1})
```

```
from multiprocessing import Process

client = None

def foo():
    # Why is client None with python 3.8? It works with python 3.5.
    print("Using client=repr(%s)" % (repr(client)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = {'hello':1}
    print("!!!Assigned client=repr(%s)" % (repr(client)))
    procs = []
    proc = Process(target=foo, args=())
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```

Weird, my python3.5 is from 2016 and doesn't even seem to be from brew so not sure where it came from. Btw I can't `brew uninstall python3` because I have packages relying on it like `awscli` and `s3cmd`, don't know why they don't use the native macOS python3 (3.7).

```
% ls -ltra /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     wheel  79 Nov 28  2016 /usr/local/bin/python3.5m-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5m-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     wheel  72 Nov 28  2016 /usr/local/bin/python3.5m -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5m
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     wheel  78 Nov 28  2016 /usr/local/bin/python3.5-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     wheel  74 Nov 28  2016 /usr/local/bin/python3.5-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     wheel  71 Nov 28  2016 /usr/local/bin/python3.5 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     wheel  72 Nov 28  2016 /usr/local/bin/python3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jamshid  staff  38 Jul 26 16:49 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jamshid  staff  45 Jul 26 16:49 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jamshid  staff  40 Jul 26 16:49 /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jamshid  staff  47 Jul 26 16:49 /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8-config
```

I guess the answer is, as tim-peters commented, the default process-creator being fork vs spawn (which creates a new process without the global being set). Yup, python 3.8 on macOS changed the default:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

> Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can lead to crashes of the subprocess. See bpo-33725.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I tried both ideone.com and repl.it. https://repl.it/@BarryMargolin/CanineThistleInitialization

Comment: I tried this on local versions of python and couldn't either.

Comment: I get `None` with python 3.7.7 and 3.8.2.

Comment: Which OS and process-creator are you using? This has always given `None` under Windows. Getting `{'hello':1}` requires that processes are created using `fork()` (impossible on Windows, the default on Linux - but, if on Linux, your environment _may_ have changed the default to "spawn").

Comment: BTW, your output shows that you're not showing us the code you actually ran. The first output contains `Assigned s3_client`, but that substring is _not_ part of the code you showed.

Comment: I removed the python3.5 remnants by removing related files and links https://en.brilliantcode.net/1214/osx-mac-completely-remove-uninstall-python/